# Reverse selected items in two drop down lists in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I’ve designed windows form application with two drop down lists.

Each drop list contains four items which are hard coded.

When a button is clicked, it should reverse the selected items. I thought of using if conditions to arrive at the solution. But, any short code will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your code (please, show us your attempt)?

Answer (score -1):

When the button is clicked, you could reasign the data sources of both drop downs:

```
 // create new list of items in order to not lose them when clearin
 var oldSource = comboBox1.Items.ToList();

 // clear old items to make them not reappear
 comboBox1.Items.Clear();

 // reverse items
 var reversedSource = oldSource.Reverse();

 // iterating over the reversedItems and adding all items
 foreach(var item in reversedSource)
 {
   comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
 }
```